# Missing 'Notebooks' tab

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed iPython Notebook as a component of my Anaconda installation.  To become familiar with using iPython Notebook I started through an introductory tutorial and immediately ran into a discrepancy.  When I open the notebook the tutorial shows I should have three tabs across the top labelled 'Notebooks', 'Running' and 'Clusters'.  Instead I have 'Files', 'Running' and 'Clusters'.  I cannot figure out how to switch the Files tab to the Notebooks tab...or is the Files tab correct and is the tutorial out-of-date?  I would much prefer to just have the Notebooks view as listing all the file folders just gets in the way.  Can someone tell me how to swap out the Files tab for the Notebooks tab?

Answer (score 0):

The three tabs "Files", "Running" and "Clusters" should be correct. The "Running" tab has the active notebooks listed.

Yes, perhaps it was an older tutorial. Do you have a link?

Comment: The tutorial is a video tutorial via my safari books online subscription.  It is called Learning iPython Notebook by James Powell, published by infinite skills in 2014.

Comment: It looks like this book is demonstrating iPython notebooks from before the creation of Jupyter in the "Big Split" (http://blog.jupyter.org/2015/04/15/the-big-split/) to make an interface that was language-agnostic. That's where the tabs must have changed, but pretty much everything you do with the notebooks should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

To start the notebook in notebook server 4.2.1, go to file tab and on the top right side, you will see `new` drop down menu. Click on the `python[root]` and it should start the new notebook.